# Javascript: How to make array from object with key value pairs as strings?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object, from which an array has to be made, where key + value pairs are converted to strings.

```
var obj = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z':3};
```

I have tried to convert the content to strings:

```
var joined = Object.entries(obj ).join(' ');

"x,1 y,2 z,3"
```

and to an array of arrays

```
var entries = Object.entries(obj);
```

But it is not exactly what I need

My ideal result is

```
var arrayFromObject = ['x 1', 'y 2', 'z 3'];
```

I can probably flatten the array of arrays but maybe there is a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use for loop for your desired output, you could've used map but it creates performance issues if the list is large.

```js
let obj = { x: 1, y: 2, z: 3 };
let outputArray = [];
for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(obj).length; i++) {
  outputArray.push(Object.keys(obj)[i]+' '+Object.values(obj)[i]);
}

console.log(outputArray);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get the desired output using [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) and [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

- Get an array of `[key, value]` pairs of a given object's properties using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).
- Iterate using [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the array values returned in first step and use [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to get the string in desired format.

```js
const obj = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3};

const array = Object.entries(obj).map(a => a.join(' '));

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know you have a KVP set, you can do something like

```
const obj = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z':3};
const result = Object.entries(obj).map(entry => `${entry[0]} ${entry[1]}`);
//(3) ["x 1", "y 2", "z 3"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Object.keys(obj).map(x => `${x} ${obj[x]}`)
```

**Explanation**

`Object.keys(obj)` returns `["x", "y", "z"]` and `map` then maps every key to a template literal `${x} ${obj[x]}` where `obj[x]` is the value (`y` is mapped to `y 2`)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const obj = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z':3};

const array = Object.entries(obj).map(a => a.join(' '));

console.log(array);
```